# Grails app require password reset daily

Tags: grails, spring-security, jetty

Here's the setup: I've deployed a very simple grails (2.4.3) app via jetty that uses the spring security plugin to handle user logins.  It works quite nicely except for one thing I can't wrap my head around.  When I check on it the next morning I have to restart jetty.

The site is still up and running and no errors have been logged.  In fact, no one has even accessed it overnight.  The problem is that no users can log in.  I've checked the db and the accounts are all enabled and non-expired.  The login just says that the user/pass is invalid.  Once I restart jetty (it doesn't muck with the db on restart either), the logins work again.

I'm stumped as to what is going on.  I'm not doing anything besides the defaults with the plugin and the app is a simple crud app that almost exclusively uses the dynamic scaffolding.  This this is just not complicated.  Any ideas about what is happening?

Answer (score 0):

My initial guess is that it has something to do with the connection pool containing invalid connections due to non-use, and for some reason a problem accessing the database is causing the login check to fail, and a generic "something went wrong" is being mis-reported as an auth failure. You might want to look into configuring the datasource so it checks pooled connections to keep them active and to also test before retrieving to ensure they're valid.

If that's not it then you should have some success using one of the approaches I describe in these two blog posts about fixing authentication problems: http://burtbeckwith.com/blog/?p=2003 and http://burtbeckwith.com/blog/?p=2029